# Proving that $f^{(3)}(x)\ge 3$ for some $x\in (-1,1)$ under some given conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Let $\displaystyle f$ be three times differentiable on $\displaystyle [ -1,1]$ such that $\displaystyle f( -1) =f( 0) =0=f'( 0)$ and $\displaystyle f( 1) =1$.

Prove that $\displaystyle f^{( 3)}( x) \geq 3$ for some $\displaystyle x\in ( -1,1) .$

I tried to prove it like this.

**Proof:** Let $\displaystyle g( x) =f( x) -\frac{x^{3}}{2}$ so that $\displaystyle g( 0) =g'( 0) =0$

Let's take $\displaystyle 1\geq x >0$. By Taylor's formula, we have:

$\displaystyle g( x) =g''( 0)\frac{x^{2}}{2} +g^{( 3)}( \xi )\frac{x^{3}}{6}$, where $\displaystyle \xi \in ( 0,x)$

and, $\displaystyle g( -x) =g''( 0)\frac{x^{2}}{2} -g^{( 3)}( \tau )\frac{x^{3}}{6}$, where $\displaystyle \tau \in ( -x,0)$

From the above, we get:

$ $$\displaystyle g( x) -g( -x) =\frac{x^{3}}{6}\left( g^{( 3)}( \xi ) +g^{( 3)}( \tau )\right) \leq \frac{1}{6}\left( g^{( 3)}( \xi ) +g^{( 3)}( \tau )\right)$

or $\displaystyle f( x) -f( -x) -x^{3} \leq \frac{1}{6}\left( g^{( 3)}( \xi ) +g^{( 3)}( \tau )\right)$

Suppose on the contrary, $\displaystyle f^{( 3)}( t) < 3$ for all $\displaystyle t\in ( -1,1)$ so that $\displaystyle g^{( 3)}( t) < 0$ for all $\displaystyle t\in ( -1,1)$.

It follows that, $\displaystyle f( x) -f( -x) -x^{3} < 0$ for all $\displaystyle x\in ( 0,1]$.

Clearly, $\displaystyle f( 1) -f( -1) -1=0$, which is a contradiction.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

Comment: See this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1905169/72031

Comment: Your proof looks good to me.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Thanks a lot for reviewing the proof. :)